# make a character jump inside canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

this is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2tLCk/4/

as you can see if you hit the up button Mario will jump far to the up and go back down once but if u hit it again he will not jump how can i fix this problem ? when I hit the up button Mario will jump to a specific location let's say y=32 and than go back down (always not just for one time ) ?

```
var Jump = function () {
        if (character.y > limit && !goingDown) {
            character.y -= limit;

        } else {
            goingDown = true;
            character.y += limit;
            if (character.y >= 184) {
                clearInterval(jumping);
                goingDown = false;
                limit = 0;
                character.y = 184;

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your fiddle has a reference error. Check the console.

Comment: there is no reference error i've checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the limit inside this if statement

```
if (keydown.up) {
    limit = 10;
    jumping = setInterval(Jump, 150);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2tLCk/15/)

To specify a specific height you can delcare a new variable called limitHeight and switch it with limit in this if statement

```
if (character.y > limitHeight && !goingDown) {
               //   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

in this new demo i also put clearInterval in the keydown.up statement to fix some bugs

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2tLCk/17/)

Comment: but still Mario is jumping to reach the x border how can i make him jump till he reach a specific y like y=32 for example

Comment: i am still not happy with the result i am trying to understand the jumping effect used in this website but i am not understanding anything :/ http://blog.nihilogic.dk/

Comment: @Sora I've copied the code from that site to this jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/w8J7L/2/

Comment: ok but can u explain the jumping code used ? and how could i make the same effect in my application ?

Comment: @Sora sry, but i won't have time to explain the jumping code used there. Btw what effect is it that you want exactly?

Comment: as u can see in the website the jumping is smooth in your solution the jumping is so fast and buggy

Comment: thank you yeah their is still one thing to do and that is fixing the current position of Mario when jumping so he don't look like he is walking in the middle air ( if i pressed left or right while jumping ) thank u for your time and your help mate :)

Comment: @Sora not sure, but you should do something like: check if jumping is active keep image jumping

Answer (score 0):

You set your limit to 0 when the jump is done. So there is 0 substracted from the y position on the second jump. In your initialization you set limit to 10. If I set limit to 10 after jump it works again.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2tLCk/12/)

Relevant code:

```
    var Jump = function () {
        if (character.y > limit && !goingDown) {
            character.y -= limit;
        } else {
            goingDown = true;
            character.y += limit;
            if (character.y >= 184) {
                clearInterval(jumping);
                goingDown = false;
                limit = 10;
                character.y = 184;

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Then mario doesn't stop jumping

Comment: exactly i want it to stop jumping after it's first jump and when i hit up again it will jump again and as u can see he jump till the border of the canvas i just want it to jump till `y=32`